# How do I get an ISV business org?

Tags: partner, lma, lmo

I have developed a managed package in a DE org, and later became approved as a Partner. I plan to put my package on AppExchange, but I need an LMO. I read somewhere that my ISV business org comes with the LMA installed. What does it mean by ISV business org? I only know about my DE org I used to develop the package, and the DE org I use for the Environment Hub.

I submitted a case on the partner community to get an ISV business org, and the case was closed with a comment telling me that I was talking about EE licenses, and they couldn't help me. Now I'm confused. How can I get an LMO?

Comment: When your app is approved and passed security review, you can submit a case to have your ISV business org provisioned, or your current org upgraded to two full licenses, or two additional licenses added depending on the status of your current business org.

Comment: Since this is reasonably answers my question, can you form it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done.................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is approved and passed security review, you can submit a case to have your ISV business org provisioned, or your current org upgraded to two full licenses, or two additional licenses added depending on the status of your current business org